# How to get the disk space on a server?

Tags: php, size

I should to develop a web-application in php for a firm, and I need to know the disk free space of the server.

At the moment, I'm able to obtain the free disk space of this kind :

```
 $quota="104857600"; //100Mb : (100*1024*1024)
```

after, I do the difference between $quota and my size variable.

So, in this case, I must to write the disk size directly in the php file...

It's possible to do the disk capacity ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[disk_free_space](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php) - Will return you the number of bytes available on the filesystem or disk partition.

[disk_total_space](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php) - Will return you the number of total bytes (i.e. capacity) on the filesystem or disk partition.

Answer (score 3):

Try  `disk_total_space` function

```
float disk_total_space ( string $directory )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php

Answer (score 1):

you can try [disk_free_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [disk_free_space](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)