# How to detect the server space enough for the uploaded file or no?

Tags: php, size

I am have uploading site and I want to know how i can know the space of the server via php ?

for example:

```
if($_FILES ...) {
  if($server_rest_space enough for the file){
    // upload it!
}
else{
  echo 'no space on your server enough!'; //there is no space!!
}
```

important another question if the server is full! and some one uploaded file is there an error will happen ?

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the disk space on a server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425841/how-to-get-the-disk-space-on-a-server)

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [`disk_free_space()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)