# How to Show Disk Usage via PHP?

Tags: php, diskspace

Does anyone have a PHP script to share that displays current server disk usage?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried googling for "php disk usage script"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the disk space on a server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425841/how-to-get-the-disk-space-on-a-server)

Comment: thanks for the down vote too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one thing PHP does really well is having [documentation that's easy to find](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+disk+usage).

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php):

```
float disk_total_space ( string $directory )
```

> Given a string containing a directory, this function will return the
>   total number of bytes on the corresponding filesystem or disk
>   partition.

Comment: if you use the above answer in conjunction with disk_free_space() function, then you will be able to figure out how much disk has been used

Comment: Thanks guys...been there on the google search :) Never had any success with exec() on my server and in my php scripts. Tried it for years.

Comment: Thanks again for the help - including @Juhana. The commands I was looking for are `disk_free_space($directory)` and `disk_total_space($directory)`. Appreciate the help!